# How can I make some progress on this Gaussian-looking integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, gaussian-integral

An old complex analysis exam question:

Evaluate

$$\large I(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2+iax}dx$$

So far, I have completed the square in exponent, and now I have the integral

$$\large I(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(x+\frac{ia}{2})^2-\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{a^2}{4}}dx$$

Perhaps completing the square above gives me an integral where I now don't have to worry about whether a is positive or negative -- and so I don't need to break the integration out into two cases.

But I'm not sure what to do from here.  Most integration that I come across in old exam questions is an application of the Residue Theorem, but currently the integrand looks pole-free / entire, so there'd be no residues to compute.

One last thing I thought of so far is that the integral looks a bit like the  Gaussian integrals.  Would this be the better / correct path to follow?  If so, what should I start with?  The $iax$ term makes it tricky to know what sort of substitution I could go with to perhaps get something like $e^{-ax^2}$

Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: This is not completing the square: $\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + 2iax) = \frac{1}{2}(x+ia)^2 + \frac{a^2}{2}$, this is... Now do you see how to proceed?

Comment: Hi @Hamed, thanks for your comment - I have completed the square correctly now.  But I am not sure how to proceed.  I am trying integration along a semi-circular contour but am not getting anywhere with it unfortunately.  What do you think could be a good choice of contour?  Thanks,

Comment: ah, I think a box in the upper half plane, that sits on the real axis could do the job, @Hamed ... I will try now ...thanks

Comment: Simply change the variable to $u=x+ia$ then you have simple Gaussian. If you are really worried that this integral is actually a real integral, note that this change of variable is equivalent to a countour with imaginary part constant $ia$. Since Gaussian has no poles in the rectangle (x axis and $z=ia$ with perpendicular lines at infinity) the Gaussian integral along the x axis (simple real Gaussian) has the same value as the new integral along $z=ia$.

Comment: Yes, agreed @Hamed.  I just finished the problem, using the Cauchy-Goursat theorem.  Thanks so much for your help :-).  Have a great night.